# Skip or filter out tests in Mocha without using only?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Would it be possible to filter tests in mocha without going through the code and adding `only` or `skip`? Let's say that I have a scenario that contains 5 tests, what I would like is to only execute one test.

Would it be possible to do it using the command line?